# i want to find same value in these data in excel how can i do that?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to find same value in these data in excel how can I do that?

```
a1=[1,2,3,4,5], b1=10,11,9
a2=[7,8,9], b2=8,5,2
```

for example compare a1 and b1 result is not match in c1
and for a2 and b2 it should print match in c2

Comment: Use TEXTSPLIT for example. Then work from there to test if at least one number does occur in both cells. For older versions start with FILTERXML and use xpath to test for dupes.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps may be something along the lines :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C1`

```
=IF(SUM(N(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(TEXTSPLIT(B1,,","),
TEXTSPLIT(A1,{"[","]"},",",1))))),"","Not ")&"Match"
```

---